# differences between s37 and elf files

Tags: c, embedded, elf, srecord

I use embedded system. After the C source code building I get many files. The file name is the same, but the extension is different:

.s37
.elf
.hex
.sig

What is the differences between them? Mainly what is the differences between .s37 and .elf?

Comment: .s37 is the raw binary in Motorola s-record format, 32 bit addresses, which can be used for production purposes. .elf is an ELF debugger standard file for your debugger only. (.hex is Intel's equivalent to s-record, roughly as popular)

Comment: .sig - I would guess a signature of some sort - tool specific and you did not specify the tool.  Your tool's documentation may help. the others are the application image in three different object file formats. .elf is usable by debuggers, S-Record and Intel Hex are ROM/Flash programming.

Answer (score 3):

Those are just different executable formats.

.s37 is one variant of [SREC format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SREC_(file_format)), it's ascii/line fixed text including hex (binary)

This format is well known by flash/upload software in most embedded targets.

`.elf` is an [executable & linkable file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), product of a linker like `gcc` or other commercial compilers (Windriver, CodeWarrior...).

`.elf` format is hardly uploadable on embedded targets without conversion to `.SREC` with `objcopy` first.
One of the main differences in contents is that `.elf` format can contain debugging symbols, whereas `.srec/.s37` cannot.

My guess is that your toolchain does it all: link: .elf, then objcopy to convert .elf to .s3 for target upload (losing symbol information if any, which requires you to keep the `.elf` file handy when debugging your application on the target, the SREC file contains only code & data, no debug).

S3 format can't contain symbols. They're discarded, even using a simple `objcopy` command. That format is only useful to contain code/data to upload on a target.

Comment: *"One of the main differences in contents is that .elf format can contain debugging symbols, whereas .srec/.s37 cannot."* - Do you have a source for .srec files not being able to contain debug information? Is there any more information that ELF files can contain but SRECs can't?

Comment: I couldn't explicitly find it (source of objcopy is far from trivial too...), but the same objcopy command with `symbolsrec` instead of `srec` as target format produces an output with symbols, when `srec` output doesn't. I've edited to clarify.